# How to show the following series converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I am trying to solve a problem from the book(A Course in Probability Theory" by Chung, Third Edition page 132). The problem says:

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables with $E(X_n)=0$. Suppose $\forall n: Var(X_n)=\sigma_n^2<\infty$ and $s^2_n=Var(\sum_{j=1}^{n}X_j)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sigma_j^2 \rightarrow \infty.$
If $a_n=s_n(log s_n)^{0.5+\epsilon}, \epsilon>0,$  then by Dini's theorem we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{E(X_n^2)}{a_n^2}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sigma_n^2}{s_n^2(log s_n)^{1+2\epsilon}}<\infty.$$
How can apply Dini's theorem? 
Thank you for help me.

Comment: You could try to find a somewhat more meaningful title for your question...